# Dispatch from GLFW's main thread using LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I am trying to call [`GLFW.glfwPollEvents()`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html) in an asynchronous task that runs every *tick* (1/30th of a second in this case). This ticking timer effectively controls when every action in the app takes place.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //... more code ...

        GLFW.glfwPollEvents();

        //... more code ...
    }
}, 33, 33);
```

But, this does not work because

> This function may only be called from the main thread.
>
> <sup>(from the documentation)</sup>

How can I call this on the main thread? When it isn't run on the main thread, the application crashes. I'm looking for something like

```
GLFW.dispatchMainThread(new GLFWRunnable(){
    public void run(){
        //...
    }
});
```

This is possible to do in `swing` and `awt` by using

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //...
    }
});
```

But the same code doesn't work for `GLFW`.

How can I run a task on `GLFW`'s main thread using LWJGL **without** using a `while(true)` loop on the main thread?

Comment: Could you add more detail about what specifically your main thread and your separate thread are doing, how the separate thread was started, should end, etc., and just the general relationship between the main and separate threads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268693/running-code-on-the-main-thread-from-a-secondary-thread); does the accepted answer there help?

Comment: @RedRoboHood No. This question is about getting the main thread on `GLFW`, not in general, as `GLFW` may have a built-in implementation. Like I say in the question, it's possible to do with `Swing`.

Comment: So the code that initializes and schedules `timer` is *not* being run on the GLFW main thread?

Comment: Are there any GLFW callbacks you can set that you could trigger from the separate thread?

Comment: @RedRoboHood Thats what this question is about - finding *something* that can make it run on the main thread

Comment: I don't see any way to do what you're asking. Could you explain in your question why exactly you can't put a loop in the main thread?

Comment: No, it won't. As the answer in the question I linked to said, you could have the main thread do other work in the loop as well and just check at intervals. Or you could use a sleep/notify system. There are many options that result in very little wasted memory and CPU cycles that you can make use of with a loop in the main thread.

Comment: @RedRoboHood True, but are there any *built-in* ways to do it with GLFW? They would be much better than anything loop that I would make.

Comment: As I said, none exist that I know of. I'm pretty sure GLFW is designed to be used with a main loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since GLFW's main thread must be the same as the application's main thread (a limitation in GLFW; that's where it puts the OS message queue that is handled differently by swing/awt it seems - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31621053/1360808)) I would do things the other way around.

My main thread would have the forever loop (probably using glfwWaitEvents so as not to eat CPU time needlessly). I would then post any events that were app-specific to another thread that does the processing. Your message processing is now decoupled from your message receiving.

This way I don't have to wait for 1/30th of a second to get OS messages (it always frustrates me when an app lags opening a menu, registering a click, or arrowing through a list).

Your update thread can even sleep for 1/30th of a second (or less, sleeping again if not enough time has passed or not if a second high-priority queue needs work) and only wake up to check for queued events as an extremely simple scheduling method.

The answer I linked to above has a link to an [LWJGL Multithreaded Demo](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/master/src/org/lwjgl/demo/opengl/glfw/Multithreaded.java) that does something very similar. Their renderLoop would be your updateLoop and would draw from a queue and do processing before going to sleep again instead of updating and presenting graphics.