# Is it possible to execute a task submitted from one thread to another existing and running thread in that another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created 2 threads. I need to submit a runnable from one thread to the other and execute it in that other thread. Is it possible?

Edit: actually I need to use main thread instead of just another one. So it is impossible to use ExecutorService.

Edit: there is the solution to this problem: [Running code on the main thread from a secondary thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268693/running-code-on-the-main-thread-from-a-secondary-thread).

I've posted below my example:

```java
public class SomeClass {

    private static Thread thread;
    private static Thread another_thread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        thread = new Thread(() -> {
            //do something
            Runnable runnable = () -> {
              //do something
            };
            //submit runnable to another_thread
            //do something else while the Runnable runnable is being executed in another_thread
        });

        another_thread = new Thread(() -> {
            //do something
        });

        another_thread.start();
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why are you creating `Thread`s directly rather than using `ExecutorService`s?

Comment: why are you trying to change it to another thread? also the .run() method on a thread doesn't actually start a thread, it just runs the runnable form your contructor in the current thread

Comment: @daniu, actually I need to execute Runnable in the main program thread, so it is impossible to use ExecutorService.

Comment: So you want to post tasks from another thread back to the main thread?

Comment: @JorisDR.I agree with you. My bad, the code is just as an example to show what I am trying to do. I didn't even run it. The real situation is much more difficult.

Comment: @JimmyB Exactly.

Comment: Maybe what you need is a [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). Otherwise, the general approach also implemented in the `Executor`s is to have a *queue* of e.g. `Runnable`s to which tasks are added by different threads and from wich tasks are taken and executed by the "worker" thread when it has time to do so.

Comment: This (executing tasks from different threads in the main thread) is a common requirement in Java-based GUIs, including Android. For these cases, the GUI frameworks provide the appropriate means, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229284/refreshing-gui-by-another-thread-in-java-swing or https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.

Comment: @JimmyB My project is not for android. I don't think that's what I am looking for.

Comment: And I don't think you give us enough information to answer your question, not even the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you usually want to do:

```
class YourClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Runnable run1 = () -> {
            Runnable run2 = createRunnable();
            // submit in second thread
            executor2.submit(run2);
        }

        // submit in first thread
        executor1.submit(run1);
    }
```

Comment: I need to execute Runnable in the main program thread, so it is impossible to use ExecutorService

Comment: I don't think you really know what you want to do. Running a Runnable in a main thread wouldn't require a runnable at all. You'd just run the code as-is.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider, the thing is, I need to run a Runnable in a main thread from another thread, while main thread is busy doing something else. I don't have direct access to the main thread, so I think I do need a Runnable. Don't you agree? [That's what I needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268693/running-code-on-the-main-thread-from-a-secondary-thread). Do you know a better solution than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16268778/11729219)?